# POST request working in Postman but not in browser (MongoDB + ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios, postman

I am creating simple form application that will input user data and insert them into MongoDB. I am using Axios for CRUD operations and all operations are working in backend (tested in Postman). When I created frontend part (ReactJS) I managed to display all users and delete them by ID. But POST method for creating new user is not working. I am getting 500 Internal server error.

Also I am using FormData and `useState`. But when calling `handleSubmit()` method, FormData is empty.

CreateUser.js

```
  const CreateUser = () => {
      const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
      const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
      const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
   
      const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.set("firstName", firstName);
        formData.set("lastName", lastName);
        formData.set("email", email);

        dispatch(createNewUser(formData)); //calling POST function from UserActions.js
      };

return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your first name"
              value={firstName}
              onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your last name"
              value={lastName}
              onChange={(e) => setLastName(e.target.value)}
            />
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter your e-mail"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button className="button" type="submit">
              Create
            </button>
       </form>
  );
};

export default CreateUser;
```

Also I am using Redux for state managment so I have my action setup too.

UserActions.js

```
export const createNewUser = (userData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post("/api/v1/user/new", userData, config);

    dispatch({
      payload: data
      
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response);
  }
};
```

Console will display message that `firstName` `lastName` `email` are empty because their `require` value is set to `true`.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your first name"],
  }.....
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

But when I am using `console.log()` to check their values on input, that works fine. Only passing those values to `formData` is not working. Or am I missing something else ?
Thanks

[image]

TLDR: FormData is empty when trying to submit inserted values to MongoDB while using Axios to POST data

Comment: Remove the `Content-type` header. You're not posting JSON, you're posting `FormData` which the browser can figure out correctly for you

Comment: Already tried that. No changes.

Comment: How are you handling the request on the server-side? Are you expecting `multipart/form-data` (using something like multer) or `application/json` (using `express.json()` or body-parser)?

Comment: I am using `express.json()`

Comment: Then don't post a `FormData` instance

Comment: Try `const formData = { firstName, lastName, email }` instead

Comment: That works. So simple solution and so silly mistake by me. I lost one whole day on that. Thank you.